# Why doesn't Stack Exchange develop an IM-like rich client to get answers real-time?

Tags: discussion

Why doesn't Stack Exchange develop an IM-like rich client for us to more conveniently ask questions and get answers in real-time?

I want to join this open source project if somebody is interested.

Comment: People shouldn't be asking so many questions that they require a dedicated application to do so.

Comment: but there is a [chat](chat.stackoverflow.com) ...

Comment: @FoxMaSk: Ok for chat, but he wanted an app for questions/answers. I think this is useless, a browser is more convenient and avoid non-constructive questions/answers.

Comment: Hi, all , I just know that Stack Overflow Chat(chat.stackoverflow.com) , and My just experience of it is amazing . Thank you .

Answer (score 8):

Real time chat has a **huge** scaleability problem:

For each question that's asked, you need (at least) one expert who can give a great answer.  That just doesn't scale, when you look at the number of questions that SO answers.

So why is the web different? Because if I *search* first, then chances are that the question that I was about to ask *has already been asked **and answered*** on Stack Overflow.

And the number of *viewers* who get the answer is *much higher* than the number of people who actually *formulate and submit the question*.

This helps greatly with scaling and replacing the web interface with real-time chat will most likely reduce the number of people who will look at the archives.

In short: SO (and Stack Exchange in general) *needs* people to ask good, high-quality questions, but they are *not* the primary audience!

Comment: I just don't get why people think real-time chat would be any better than real-time Q&A. What motivates these feature requests? *If only there were more noise and fewer answers...then this site would be great!*

Comment: @CodyGray: and we could make a way to answer to answers. And we could display them in a threaded form ... no, even better: display them chronologically, so that you can easily see which answer came first. And don't let other users edit my stuff, because that's just mean!